# Overloaded inline operators in F#: ( |+| )

Tags: syntax, f#, operator-overloading

I'm trying to define an overloaded operator, e.g. `|+|`, as the following:

```
let inline ( |+| ) (m1 : #IMeasurable) (m2 : #IMeasurable) = m1.Measure + m2.Measure
```

The problem is, I can't do something like:

```
let three = m1 |+| m2 |+| m3
```

Because the operator `|+|` isn't defined for the case `(m1 : int) (m2 : #IMeasurable)`. Is there a way to overload this operator or use static type constraints to make the above expression possible? Is there a way to modify `IMeasurable` (which I can edit) so that this is possible? Anything else that would allow the above expression to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
type Overloads = Overloads with
    static member ($) (Overloads, m1: #IMeasurable) = fun (m2: #IMeasurable) -> m1.Measure + m2.Measure 
    static member ($) (Overloads, m1: int) = fun (m2: #IMeasurable) -> m1 + m2.Measure

let inline ( |+| ) m1 m2 = (Overloads $ m1) m2
```

Not tested, since I don't have IMeasurable, but it may do the job.

Answer (score 6):

If you're defining an operator that behaves like `+` then I think the best design is to define an operator that returns a value of the same type as is the type of its arguments. This means that I would change the operator to return `IMeasurable` instead of `int`:

```
type IMeasurable =
  abstract Measure : int

let newMeasure m = 
  { new IMeasurable with 
      member x.Measure = m }

let inline ( |+| ) (m1 : #IMeasurable) (m2 : #IMeasurable) = 
  newMeasure (m1.Measure + m2.Measure)
```

This will make the operator definition more uniform and easier to use. The code you wanted to write will now work (returning `IMeasurable`), but you can also use `Seq.reduce`:

```
// Now you can add multiple measure values without issues
let res = (newMeasure 2) |+| (newMeasure 3) |+| (newMeasure 4)

// Moreover, you can also use `Seq.reduce` which would not work
// with your original operator (because it has wrong type)
let res = [newMeasure 2; newMeasure 3; newMeasure 4] |> Seq.reduce (|+|)
```

That said, if you really want to overload an operator that is defined using `let` and you cannot add it to a type as static member (because you cannot modify the type), then you'll need to use the trick that Gustavo describes

Comment: Returning an `IMeasurable` doesn't make sense in this case, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hmm, if returning `IMeasurabe` does not make logical sense then you'd probably need to follow the suggestion from @Gustavo. Although maybe that means that having a simple function that converts `IMeasurable` to an `int` and then using standard `+` for `int`s would be a good alternative. Custom operators are quite difficult to discover while something like `m1.Measure + m2.Measure + m3.Measure` is not too long and easy to write & understand.