# Handling "The resulting type would be infinite when unifying"

Tags: recursion, f#, bind

`let rec bind x f = f x |> bind 
 bind "Hello World" (fun x -> x.toUpper()) printf "%s"`

The code snippet above results in this error "The resulting type would be infinite when unifying".

The compiler's suggestion: "Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of the object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved."

As the compiler said adding a type annotation would resolve this problem. How would you write a type annotation which satisfies the compiler?

This might be helpful. Since Javascript is more forgiving and it doesn't complain, you can look at a working example of the same piece of code translated into JS.

```js
const bind = x => f => bind(f(x))

bind("Hello World")
(x => x.toUpperCase())
(console.log)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `bind` function you are trying to define does not have a type that you can express in standard F#. You want a function that has a type looking something like this:

```
'A -> ('A -> 'B) -> ('B -> 'C) -> ('C -> 'D) -> ('D -> 'E) -> ....
```

In other word, the `bind` function should take input and a sequence of functions that it applies to them, but you're not restricting how long the sequence is. The standard F# type system does not have a way of expressing this and so people usually use other patterns. In your case, it would be the `|>` operator. In contrast to your `bind`, you have to write `|>` repeatedly, but that's typically fine:

```
"Hello World" 
|> (fun x -> x.ToUpper()) 
|> printf "%s"
```

That said, I think your example is not well chosen, and I'd just write:

```
printf "%s" ("Hello world".ToUpper())
```

Finally, it might be actually possible to define something like your `bind` function using overloading that's possible thanks to F# static member constraints. Something along [those lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12971965/overloaded-inline-operators-in-f/12972293#12972293), but `|>` is an idiomatic and clean solution for doing the thing that your example illustrates.

Comment: Beat me to it! I'll go ahead and finish my answer, though, as I went in some directions you didn't.

Comment: @rmunn I'm not surprised I was a few second earlier, given how detailed your answer is! I'm sure it's worth keeping both around!

Comment: Your summary of the type of `bind` as `'A -> ('A -> 'B) -> ('B -> 'C) -> ('C -> 'D) -> ('D -> 'E) -> ....` is terrific, and IMHO does a better job of explaining the infinite nature of the type than my long-winded answer did. (Though I agree that it's worth keeping both around, since people have different learning styles and it's therefore worth having something explained in two different ways).

Answer (score 1):

**Summary:** you can't do this, but that function isn't useful in F#; just use the `|>` operator instead.

**Longer version:** there is no way to annotate the `bind` function that you've described in a way that will satisfy the F# compiler. When I paste `let rec bind x f = f x |> bind` into F# Interactive, it gives me the following error:

> ```
> error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
>     ''a -> 'b'    
> but given a
>     ''a -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'b'    
> The types ''b' and '('a -> 'a) -> 'b' cannot be unified.
> ```

If we rearrange the definition a little to look like `let rec bind x f = bind (f x)` instead, we get a slightly simplified type error:

> ```
> error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
>     ''a'    
> but given a
>     ''b -> 'a'    
> The types ''a' and ''b -> 'a' cannot be unified.
> ```

With a bit of type hinting (`let bind (x : 'x) (f : 'f) = ...`), we get the error that the types `'a` and `'f -> 'a` cannot be unified, so it becomes clear what's going on. `'a` is the return type of `bind` (in the absence of any names for generic types, F# assigns them starting with `'a`). Now let's look at why this type error is happening.

It looks like tou already know about partial application: any two-argument function, when given a single argument, returns a function that waits for its second argument before evaluating the function body. In other words, `let f a b = ...` in F# is equivalent to the Javascript `const f = a => b => ...`. Here, the `bind` function, when given a single argument `x`, returns a function that waits for an `f` before evaluating the body of `bind`. That means that when `bind` is passed a single parameter, its return type is `'f -> 'a` (where `'a` is, as we said, the name that the F# compiler has arbitrarily assigned to the result of `bind`).

However, here's where the type conflict comes in: the value `bind (f x)`, which has the value of `'f -> 'a` as we've already said, *is also the result of your `bind` function*. That means that it should have the type `'a`. So the F# compiler would need to compile that function in such a way that the type `'a` is the same type as `'f -> 'a`. If that were possible, then in type algebra `'a = 'f -> 'a`, and you could then expand the `'a` in the right-hand side of that equation to be `'f -> 'a`, so that the equation becomes `'a = 'f -> ('f -> 'a)`. You could now expand the `'a` again, getting `'a = 'f -> ('f -> ('f -> 'a))`. And so on infinitely. The F# compiler does not allow infinitely-expanding types, so this is not allowed.

But as I already pointed out (and Tomas Petricek explained), you don't actually need this `bind` function in F#. All it is is a way to hook functions into a pipeline, where the output of one function will be passed into the input of the next one (as your Javascript example demonstrates). And in F#, the idiomatic way to do this is with the "pipeline" operator. Instead of `bind "input value" f1 f2 f3` (where f1, f2 and f3 are three functions of appropriate type), in F# you'd simply write:

```
"input value"
|> f1
|> f2
|> f3
```

This is normal, idiomatic F# and will be understood by pretty much anyone, even those who aren't particularly familiar with functional programming. So there's no need for this `bind` function in F#.

Comment: You're a champ rmunn, I like the robin picture you have as an avatar and I very much appreciate that you've went to the lengths of typing the code into the F# Interactive and explaining the type system rationale, combining your's and Tomas Petricek's answer would be ideal that's why I voted them both up but in the end I chose Tomas's answer by a hair because it mentions overloading as a possible way of implementing the bind function.

Answer (score 0):

That definition of `bind` is a functional paradox. It is self contradictory.

```
let rec bind a f = f a |> bind
//  val bind: (a:'a) -> (f:'a->'a) -> 'b
```

The best way to see it is by adding some type annotations, lets replace `'a` with `int` to make it more concrete:

```
let rec bind (a:int) (f:int->int) = f a |> bind
//  val bind:(a:int) -> (f:int->int)-> 'a
```

`bind` receives a number and a function that takes the number and returns another, but what does `bind` return? The system does not know because it never really returns anything, it only goes deeper and deeper into another level of currying. That in itself is not a problem, F# can handle routines that never exit, for instance:

```
let rec loop() = printfn "Hello" ; loop()
//  val loop : unit -> 'a
```

In fact you can annotate `loop` with any type and F# would be OK with that:

```
let rec loop() : float = printfn "Hello" ; loop()
//  val loop : unit -> float
```

But if we do the same with `bind` the contradiction becomes apparent:

```
let rec bind (a:int) (f:int->int) : string = f a |> bind
//  val bind:(a:int) -> (f:int->int)-> string
```

The error message says:

```
Expecting a 'int -> string' but given a 'int -> (int -> int) -> string'
```

Why is it expecting `int -> string`? Because it is what the type says. We know `f a` returns an `int` and we pass it to `bind` and we should get a `string`, because that is the final result of the function. But `bind` does not return a `string` when only one parameter is passed, instead it returns a function of type `(f:int->int)-> string`, there in lies the contradiction. The left side (of the `=`) says `bind` returns a `string` when receiving 2 parameters but the right side says it returns a 'string' when receiving 1 parameter. It is a paradox, like the statement 'I always lie'.

If we go back to the initial definition without type annotations we can see that the inferred result type of bind is `'b` which means any type, but it has to be one specific type not many types or a type that changes on every call. In particular `'b` cannot be equal to `('a->'a) -> 'b` because it involves `'b` and thus is a circular definition (or maybe elliptical), hence the infinite loop.

For Javascript it is not a problem because it does not care about what types are passed to or returned from functions. That is they key feature that makes F# so much better to work with than Javascript.